# How to generate id of a list item in sharepoint 2013 using jsom. And what is easy way in client side?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, jsom

following is the code:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="ResultDiv"></div>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">  

function getListItem(url, listname, id, complete, failure) {
alert('hi');
    // Getting our list items
    $.ajax({
        url:'http://wzspf2:300/sites/Sample'/ + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + CompanyInfo + "')/items(" + id + ")",
        method: "GET",
        headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
        success: function (data) {
            // Returning the results
            complete(data);
        },
        error: function (data) {
            failure(data);
        }
        });
    }
} 
</script>
```

but i am getting failed to load error. Please give me solution asap. Can you explain how to retrieve lookup values in sharepoint list

Answer (score 0):

Check your url. Seems like you have a backslash after .../Sample

In order to get Lookup values you have to use the expand and select operator.

Look here [link](https://threewill.com/using-the-expand-odata-query-option-in-sharepoint-2013/)

Comment: It shows an error that failed to open  http://wzspf2:300/sites/Sample/SitePages/Bahunya/QuerytogetID.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Change the url property to:

```
url: "http://wzspf2:300/sites/Sample" + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + CompanyInfo + "')/items(" + id + ")"
```

I also can give you the advice to use pnp js for REST calls. With pnp js it is much easier to work with.

If you want to receive LookUp Values you have to use expand and select operator as mentioned before. So for example if List "CompanyInfo" has a column called myLookUp which is a LookUp to another List you can use something like:

```
url: "http://wzspf2:300/sites/Sample" + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + CompanyInfo + "')/items(" + id + ")" + "?$expand=myLookUp&$select=myLookUp/Id"
```

Please let us know if you got it to work.